# Cannot set backend for VideoCapture in Opencv 3.2.0

Tags: c++, opencv, v4l2

I like to catch a video given by a usb webcam with opencv. For this I try to use the VideoCapture class, with the v4l2 backend. Following the example at https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html I call the constructor in a the following way:

```
VideoCapture vc(id + CAP_V4L2);
```

where id indicates my camera (here 0).

To check for success I did something like this:

```
cout << vc.get(CAP_PROP_MODE)<<endl; // return 0 instead of the value of CAP_V4L2
```

I also make sure to compile opencv with V4L/V4L2. getBuildInformation() shows the following line:

V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.14.2) / libv4l2 (ver 1.14.2))

Currently  I'm working in a Virtualbox 6.0.4 with a Ubuntu 18.04 guest system and also a Ubuntu 18.04 system as host.

Here is a minimum example:

```
int main() {
    int id = 0;
    VideoCapture vc(id + CAP_V4L2);
    if(!vc.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open cam " << std::endl;
        exit(-1);    
    } 
    cout << vc.get(CAP_PROP_MODE) << " | " << CAP_V4L2 <<endl; // 0 | 200
}
```

I am thankful for every help

Comment: There is no wrong with ur code and work properly, I couldnt understand the problem exactly

Comment: I was expecting that vc.get(CAP_PROP_MODE) also returns 200, to show that the backend was set correctly.

Comment: But they re not same thing CAP_V4L2 and CAP_PROP_MODE

Comment: Maybe I interpret it in a wrong way, but imho CAP_PROP_MODE shall return the choosen backend, in this case CAP_V4L2?

Comment: The description of `CAP_PROP_MODE` says: "Backend-specific value indicating the current capture mode." -- that's definitely not the same thing as "ID of the backend". | If you can upgrade a little, there's [`getBackendName`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a4576e03f447abfdbd602c0809824ec03) since release 3.4.4.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this clarification.